# Destructive processing of string in ForEach-Object loop?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell, and learning the ins and outs of how cmdlets work.  I have three paths, and I'd like to ensure that they all have trailing slashes.  The following code should check each one and append a \ if not present, however it doesn't end up changing the variables themselves.

```
# append trailing slash if not present
$engineXCopyPath, $engineXBackupPath, $enlistmentBuildTargetPath | ForEach-Object {
    if(!$_.EndsWith("\")) {
        $_ += "\"
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
# append trailing slash if not present
$engineXCopyPath, $engineXBackupPath, $enlistmentBuildTargetPath =
$engineXCopyPath, $engineXBackupPath, $enlistmentBuildTargetPath | ForEach-Object {
    if(!$_.EndsWith("\")) {
        $_ + "\"
    }
    else {
        $_ # keep the original value if appending isn't needed
    }       
}
```

Comment: That worked!  I still don't really understand what the `$_` does, and without knowing its name, it's difficult to search for that.  Can you throw me a link for further reading?

Comment: $_ is the value of the current object in the pipeline, not the actual object.  This solution uses indirection (=) to calculate a new value using the exiting value, and re-assign that back to the original object.  I'm kind of at a loss to come up with a link that explains that explicitly.  Maybe somebody else can.